# HTTP multipart/form-data over Socket does not show the variables

Tags: http, post, multipart, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm now already trying for hours, but somehow i don't figure out the problem. Here is a sample of my Request:

```
POST /test/upload/upload.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
User-Agent: TestBrowser
Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=635131229269 //edited
Content-Length: 94

--635131229269
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testme"

contender
--635131229269--
```

It is sended over standard TCP/IP Socket to a PHP Server, but the $_POST['testme'] Value is always empty.

Does someone can see the bug in this Request? --> solved

There is a \r\n at the end which doesn't show in the Code here.

Thank you, that solved my first problem.

Maybe you can help my with my second aswell. As i had seen on your profile you are well with C# and there is my second problem. I'm trying to upload a file to my server and the filedata somehow does not requested properly, i think it's because of the encoding, but i'm not sure.

```
_content = _content
     + "--" + boundary + Environment.NewLine
     + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + this._FileVarName + "\"; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(this._FilePath) + "\""
     + Environment.NewLine + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/octet-stream"
     + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

mainContent = this.Combine(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_content), StreamFile(this._FilePath));

private Byte[] StreamFile(string Path)
{
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  Byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
  fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
  fs.Close();
  return ImageData;
}
```

Comment: You should make a new question and link to this instead of asking a second question.

Comment: After 3 years, really??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the boundary (on line 4) without the leading dashes. Also I only count 92 bytes of payload.

Comment: Thank you, that was it, but now it's coming to the next (see above)

Comment: @DaMaex try to open a new question for that and please show what you have tried and what data is being sent (using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) for example).

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this answer a bit more complete, there has to be a semicolon after "multipart/form-data" (see [w3c forms spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2))

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=635131229269
```

Comment: Sure, it's a bit old but yeah, i had already seen this aswell, but thank you too.